# FileNotFoundException when loading Nuget package referenced by dynamically-loaded assembly

Tags: .net-core

I am upgrading a .NET Framework application to .NET Core 3 and have run into an issue:

My application has two assemblies, let's call them `Alpha` (an executable) and `Beta` (a library). Both are .NET Core 3 projects in the same solution, but `Alpha` does *not* directly reference `Beta`. `Beta` references a 3rd-party Nuget package `Charlie` (a .NET Standard 1.1 library).

`Alpha` loads `Beta` dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFile(@"Path\To\Beta.dll")`. This works fine, and `Alpha` is able to call into `Beta` (using reflection) successfully, except that an exception is thrown once it automatically tries to load the `Charlie` assembly as needed by `Beta`:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Charlie, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

This worked fine in .NET Framework but seems to not work in .NET Core. Both `Beta` and `Charlie` are copied into `Alpha`'s output folder.

Adding `Beta` as a reference to `Alpha` makes it work, but I'd prefer not to do that since `Alpha` has no business directly calling anything in `Beta` (except for a couple well-defined methods invoked via reflection).

How can I fix this, without adding `Beta` or `Charlie` as a dependency of `Alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if I load the `Beta` assembly using [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_) instead of `Assembly.LoadFile` then it works, but I don't understand why. If someone can post an explanation of why, then I'll happily accept and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Suzanne Cook explained in her [blog post about LoadFrom vs LoadFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom/):

> **LoadFrom()** goes through Fusion and can be redirected to another
> assembly at a different path but with that same identity if one is
> already loaded in the LoadFrom context.
>
> **LoadFile()** doesn't bind
> through Fusion at all - the loader just goes ahead and loads exactly*
> what the caller requested. It doesn't use either the Load or the
> LoadFrom context.
>
> So, **LoadFrom()** usually gives you what you asked for, but not
> necessarily. **LoadFile()** is for those who really, really want exactly
> what is requested. (*However, starting in v2, policy will be applied
> to both **LoadFrom()** and **LoadFile()**, so **LoadFile()** won't necessarily be
> exactly what was requested. Also, starting in v2, if an assembly with
> its identity is in the GAC, the GAC copy will be used instead. Use
> ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() to load exactly what you want - but, note
> that assemblies loaded that way can't be executed.)
>
> **LoadFile()** has a catch. Since it doesn't use a binding context, its
> dependencies aren't automatically found in its directory. If they
> aren't available in the Load context, you would have to subscribe to
> the AssemblyResolve event in order to bind to them.

You can find out which binding context suites you [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/choosing-a-binding-context/).

Comment: Thanks! So why does LoadFile work in .NET Framework but not in .NET Core?

Comment: If the same class is loaded into two separate AssemblyLoadContexts they are treated as different types. .NET core does not support automatically marshalling types across these boundaries. In this case Assembly.LoadFile is creating a separate AssemblyLoadContext. You can learn more about marshalling behavior [here in msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior).